# About discrete and trivial spaces and continuous functions.

Tags: general-topology

There's a problem I've been working on and it states the following:

Let $X$ be a topological space.

1. Prove that $X$ is discrete if and only if for every space $Y$ and every function $f:X\to Y$, f is continuous.
2. Prove that $X$ is trivial if and only if for every space $Z$ and every function $g:Z\to X$, $g$ is continuous.

Here is my attempt:

1. We have that for every open subset $V$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ since $X$ is discrete, and so, we can conclude that $f$ is continuous.
   Then for the other implication, let $U$ be an open set in $X$, then since for every space $Y$ and every function $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is continuous, we have that exists a space $Y$ such that exists $V$ open in $Y$ which has the property $f^{-1}(V)=U$, and since this is for every open set of $X$ we can conclude that $X$ is discrete.
2. Since $X$ is a trivial space, the only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$, then the inverse image from said sets are $Y$ and $\emptyset$, respectively, so we have that for every space $Y$, $g:Z\to X$ is continuous.
   For the other part, we considere $g=id$, and $Z$ with the trivial topology, then we know that if $id:Z\to X$ so then the topology in $X$ is trivial.

Now I am particularly unsure for the $(\Leftarrow)$ parts of the proof, am I correct? Is there something I need to pay atention to? Sorry if my english is a bit broken and thanks for reading.

Comment: Your trick for 2 works for 1 as well and it is a little faster. Let $Y = X$ as sets, equip $Y$ with the discrete topology, let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be the identity. Now for every $U \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(U) = U$ is open, so $X$ is discrete. For the implication in 2, you mixed up $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Also just to clarify, for the converse of 2 you should say something about a contradiction. Let $Z = X$ as sets, equip $Z$ with the trivial topology, let $g : Z \rightarrow X$ be the identity map. Suppose $U \subseteq X$ is not the empty set or $X$ and is open. Then $g^{-1}(U) = U$ would be open, but $Z$ has the trivial topology, contradiction.

Comment: I've corrected the detail in 2. Also thanks for the clarifications and observations, really liked using the identity as well for 1. I just didn't see it. 
Was trying to make a contradiction arise in the converse from 2. son thanks for that also.