# What is wrong with the term "indiscrete topology"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I have noticed recently e.g., in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474161/about-discrete-and-trivial-spaces-and-continuous-functions) that the term "trivial topology" is being used in place of (what I believe to be) the traditional term "indiscrete topology". Is there any reason for this change? To me, the discrete and indiscrete topologies are both trivial, so this change seems like a confusing and retrograde step.

Comment: I agree. If we're going to use trivial in the sense of its place in the power set of the space (not a great choice since it has two open sets rather than just the empty set but it is *the most trivial* among topologies), then shouldn't the discrete topology be the *improper* topology, as it's the improper subset? I digress. :-)

Comment: I don't understand how you jumped from "a user on MS used a reasonably common alternative term for 'indiscrete topology'" to "what is wrong with the term indiscrete topology". There is no "change". The user is just used to a slightly different terminology than you are.

Comment: @Pilcrow: my point is that I don't understand the reason for adopting the alternative terminology, which appears to me to be relatively new and rather unclear, whereas what I believe to the traditional terminology leaves no room for confusion. Please read my question and note my use of terms like "e.g." before accusing me of jumping to opinions.

Comment: I don't have enough of a historical memory to have an opinion on whether there indeed has been a change, but my point is that there is no implied claim that there is something *wrong* with the term "indiscrete" being made by people who use the term "trivial". It's probably not the case that they learned the term "indiscrete" but then changed to "trivial" because they felt that there was something *wrong* with the term "indiscrete".

Comment: I've learned that fighting terminology changes is a losing battle. The community makes up its own mind through usage. At one point I got annoyed that people were using "transversal" when they meant "transverse," but really nobody seemed to care other than myself. I once had a referee complain when I said "We induct on n." His point was that the verb form should be "induce," even though "induct" has pretty wide usage.

Comment: Which tradition are you following? A cursory search on google's books ngram viewer reveals that "trivial topology" predates "indiscrete topology". Earliest reference to "trivial topology" I could find was from 1951 where it is contrasted to "discrete topology". Subsequent snippets from books tend to specify "indiscrete" and "trivial" as synonymous. It's only in the 60s that "indiscrete topology" starts to appear by itself (at least according to my perusal of snippers from books.google).

Comment: In any case, both terms appear with equal frequency in my experience, so I feel the question is moot.

Comment: I've seen both often, and until I just now learned of its age, "indiscrete" struck me as a "made up word" in analogy with "indiscreet" that was unclear as it sounds like it just means "not the discrete topology". I prefer "trivial" because it clearly refers to the minimal topology just like "trivial" often means in other contexts.

Comment: @MarkS. "indiscreet" dates back to 15th century, "indiscrete" to 1600, the latter a changed spelling of the former to used to promote its secondary meaning, at least according to etymonline...

Comment: Nothing beats “Klumpentopologie”, but sometimes you have to use English.

Comment: @CarstenS: Klumpentopologie is briliant (presumably for the indiscrete topology which treats the whole space as one big clump). What do you call the discrete topology in German?

Comment: @RobArthan, for the discrete topology i don't know anything but "diskrete Topologie". But that's a good term in my opinion. And i would consider Klumpentopologie for the trivial topology a colloquial term.

Answer (score 4):

The discrete and indiscrete topologies aren't quite equally trivial from the localic point of view; the indiscrete topology, viewed in terms of its open sets, has the minimum open sets required by the axioms (just $\emptyset$ and the whole set), so arguably it is the "freest" or "most trivial" topology on a fixed set. The corresponding locale (which is the same for all indiscrete spaces; note that discrete spaces by contrast all correspond to different locales) is the terminal locale, which roughly corresponds to the point being the terminal topological space.

Comment: I understand your point, but it doesn't seem to me to be a good reasons for singling out the indiscrete topology as the trivial one when the subject matter in question is traditional point-set topology rather than localic topology.

Comment: Qiaochu, I'm curious if you have any comments on the category-theoretic aspect I broached in my answer. I'm not a category theorist myself, but I suspect there's a bit more to say than I have.

Comment: @Noah: well, the basic observation is that the discrete and indiscrete topology functors are respectively the left and right adjoints of the forgetful functor $\text{Top} \to \text{Set}$, so preserve colimits and limits respectively - this is one way to see why coproducts of discrete spaces are discrete and products of indiscrete spaces are indiscrete, and is one way to put the discrete and indiscrete topologies on equal footing (another, which I guess is more or less equivalent, is to view them as the top and bottom elements of the lattice of topologies on a fixed set).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Derp, not my finest moment. Incorporated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small argument in favor of the term "trivial" in this context - or at least, for the implicit claim that the indiscrete topology is **more trivial than** the discrete topology.

I'd argue that any reasonable notion of "triviality" should be preserved under the standard constructions - namely **quotients**, **substructures** (or in this case sub**spaces**), and **products**. Now while it's true that quotients and substructures of discrete spaces are again discrete, (infinitary) products of discrete spaces need not be discrete and can in fact be quite interesting. By contrast, products of indiscrete spaces remain indiscrete.

*Wait, what about **co**products? That's a fair point, but I think - duality notwithstanding - the naive intuition behind triviality plays better with products than coproducts. On a hopefully-ameliorating note, I'd be happy referring to the discrete topology as "cotrivial."*

There is probably a more sophisticated observation to be made here along the same lines in terms of the two **functors** $$\mathscr{Dis}, \mathscr{Ind}:{\bf Sets}\rightarrow{\bf Top}$$ sending a set $X$ to the discrete and indiscrete topology on $X$ respectively; not being a category theorist, however, I'll content myself with the relatively elementary observation above. (EDIT: as Qiaochu Yuan [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474303/what-is-wrong-with-the-term-indiscrete-topology/4474315#comment9379310_4474309), I'm actually making this seem more mysterious than it is: the point is just that these are the left and right adjoints of the forgetful functor ${\bf Top}\rightarrow{\bf Sets}$ respectively and so preserve colimits and limits respectively.)

---

EDIT: Another justification comes from logic. In logic, we often think of a topology on a set $X$ as corresponding to some notion of "information" about elements of $X$; in particular, the (basic) open sets in the topology correspond to the "atomic observations" that our type of information provides us with.

An indiscrete topology corresponds to **no information whatsoever** (all points look identical), while a discrete topology corresponds to **as much information as possible**. Only the former makes sense, to me at least, as a kind of triviality.

---

In general, as I've gone through point-set topology from various perspectives, I've found more and more reasons to think of indiscrete topologies as trivial and discrete topologies as not-so-trivial. Adopting this terminology from the get-go would, in my opinion, constitute useful terminological foreshadowing.

Comment: Yes, but what is the advantage in terms of pedagogy or clear discourse for not using the term "indiscrete" that has been standard for decades?

Comment: @RobArthan I would say that the advantage is that this usage implicitly emphasizes the **non-triviality** of discrete spaces - which is a common stumbling point for students (namely, around proving that products of discrete spaces need not be discrete). There actually is a meaningful kind of triviality present in indiscrete spaces and absent in discrete spaces, and highlighting that does in my opinion make things clearer.

Comment: But coproducts of indiscrete spaces aren't necessarily indiscrete. However, my objections to changes in traditional terminology always seem to be deprecated on MSE, so I'll just sit quietly in the corner from now on (unless provoked).

Comment: @RobArthan "But coproducts of indiscrete spaces aren't necessarily indiscrete." I addressed that in my answer - I generally think that the naive idea of triviality **does** play better with products than coproducts (and I correspondingly **would** support using the term "cotrivial" for the discrete topology). You're right that I'm indulging in a nontrivial (hehe) value judgment here, but it is a value judgment I stand behind and think is pedagogically good.

Comment: So (being now provoked), why are the terms "trivial" and "cotrivial" better than "indiscrete" and "discrete", when the latter pair clearly capture the geometric intuition behind the notions?

Comment: @RobArthan First of all, I'm not certain that the latter pair do capture the geometric intuition. "Indiscrete" in natural language after all means "saying *too much*," and I've had several students confuse discrete and indiscrete for this reason. Second of all, geometric intuition isn't the only relevant kind of intuition; there is also what I'll call "**strategic** intuition," that is, intuition for how a concept will be used in mathematics later on. Both in a standard first-semester point-set topology class and beyond, discrete topologies play a much more important role than indiscrete ones.

Comment: That is, if "indiscrete topology" better conveys *what they look like* (and per the above I'm not certain it does), "trivial topology" better conveys *how they get used*. I personally value this sort of strategic intuition when it can be provided at relatively low cost, and I would argue that this is indeed a "relatively low cost" situation.

Comment: You are getting "discreet" and "discrete" mixed up. "discrete" means divided into separate parts, which exactly matches the intuition behind the use of the term in topology. (I am not immediately convinced by your notion of strategic intuition, but I will reflect on it.)

Comment: @RobArthan That was slightly tongue-in-cheek; my point was that students aren't great with homophones. The strategic intuition point, though, was more serious and is my real argument.

Comment: Perhaps I am taking a "tactical" view rather than a "strategic" one: once you're recalled what "discrete" and "indiscrete" mean (when spelled that way), the geometrical  intuition behind the two extremal topologies becomes immediate and when you take on board their role in the definition of continuity, they both enjoy a certain kind of triviality. If your students aren't good with homophones, perhaps this would be a good opportunity to help them.